# UITextField in UITableViewCell - reuse issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` which has a custom `UITableViewCell` that has a `UITextField` inside it.

Each `UITextField` displays some text from my `viewModel` and I am using `Reactive-Cocoa` to bind the textfields to the `viewModel`.

When my `UITableView` loads for the first time, everything works just fine. However when I reload the `UiTableView` for the next 'page' - the first `UiTextField` on reloaded (page two) tableView has the exact same memory address as the first `UITextField` in the first 'page' - cell is not the same as other UI Elements are correct - just the textfields are the same instance.

So, I declared the `UITextField`s in my VC like so:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic)  UITextField *textFieldOne; //One the first 'page'
@property (weak, nonatomic)  UITextField *textFieldTwo; //After reload on second 'page'
```

Then setup then up like so in a method invoked by `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 -(void)configureTextFieldCell:(BBTextFieldLabelTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        cell.textField.delegate = self;

        if (self.selectedSegmentIndex == SegmentedControlStep1){
            if (indexPath.section == 0){

                            cell.label.text = @"Name";
                            self.textFieldOne = cell.textField;
                    }
                /* Code for setting up other cells / textfields ommited -
                but the same syntax as above with checks for indexPath */
                }

        if (self.selectedSegmentIndex == SegmentedControlStep2){

                cell.label.text = @"Username";
                self.textFieldTwo = cell.textField;

            [self bindUsernameAndPasswordToViewModel]; /* Binding for this textfield as its nil when VC loads for the first time,
                                                            so this is the first chance I get to bind it on second page */
        }
    }
```

Inside `BBTextFieldLabelTableViewCell` the `UITextField` is declared like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
```

I also tried doing this inside the cell's implementation file:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
}
```

As I thought my issue is possibly a cell-reuse issue of some sort. 
However this code made no difference.

So `textFieldOne` and `textFieldTwo` both have the exact same memory address and I cannot figure out why.

Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I create the cell like so:

```
BBTextFieldLabelTableViewCell *textFieldCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:textFieldCellidentifier];
```

Comment: Did you check the memory address of cell?

Comment: Interesting... address is the same and on some occasions, the UI elements are incorrect. It seems like UITableView is reusing the exact cell and not updating the content correctly. Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: You can make a different custom cell for your second screen if the purpose and UI are different..

Comment: @AnushaK UI is the same, except the UILabel in the cell. Sometimes the label is set incorrectly (To the same value as the one on the first page) - seems like UITableView is using the exact same cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your prepareForReuse you are creating a new text-field but you are neither removing the old one nor adding the new one.

I suggest using prepareForReuse to reset the current text field rather than creating a new one

Reading your question a bit more carefully: The fact that textfield one and two both have the same value, indicates that prepare for reuse is not being called between the two calls to configureTextFieldCell. Without more code, it is difficult to understand why

Comment: Just check; prepareForReuse is being called. I also changed it to reset the textField instead of creating a new one. However I am still having issues where the tableView is reusing the wrong cell. cellForRowAtIndexPath just calls configureTextFieldCell - nothing special in there. I have updated my question with the creation of the cell.

Comment: @Tander What do you mean by tableView is reusing the wrong cell. Do you mean reused cell's old content is not cleared??

Comment: @SFF Yes, exactly that. However taking Yaser's suggestion seems to have fixed something as I am no longer seeing the bug. I wish I knew why though. Will update question with an answer if I figure out what was causing it.

Comment: @Tander As Yaser said, old content doesn't get cleared unless you remove it from the cell. I had a same problem and fixed it by removing the cell's contentView before reuse and adding it again in cellForRow.

Comment: @SFF Yes that cleared the content - however it seems for some reason the textFields were still confused. (Same memory addresses). I

Comment: Best advice I can give you is to try and understand the lifecycle of each cell. From your description it seems as if textFieldOne and textFieldTwo should be different. Note that that was with your old code (where prepareForReuse created a new text field). In the current code, where you just clear the text field, the pointers should be the same.