# ReactiveCocoa connection to UICollectionViewCell subview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, reactive-cocoa

I have a `UICollectionView` which loads my custom `UICollectionViewCell`'s that have a `UITextField` in them and a `UILabel`.

In my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I am doing something like this:

```
        -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        BBCollectionViewTextFieldCell *textFieldCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[BBCollectionViewTextFieldCell reuseIdentifier] forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *label = @"";

                switch (indexPath.item){
                    case 0:
                        label = @"Label One";
                        self.firstTextField = textFieldCell.textField;
                        textFieldCell.textField.text = self.viewModel.labelOneData;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        label = @"Label Two";
                        self.secondTextField = textFieldCell.textField;
                        textFieldCell.textField.text = self.viewModel.labelTwoData;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        label = @"Label Three";
                        self.thirdTextField = textFieldCell.textField;
                        textFieldCell.textField.text = self.viewModel.labelThreeData;
                        break;
                     }

                   textFieldCell.label.text = label;
                    textFieldCell.textField.delegate = self;
    return textFieldCell; 
    }
```

I then use the normal `UITextFieldDelegate` methods to handle text input doing something like this:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

if (textField == self.firstTextField){
   //Do something with it
}
//And so on for the rest... 
}
```

So far so good and all works...

**So what's the issue?**

The issue is if I reload the `UICollectionView` the following happens:

- `self.firstTextField` will have data in it that belongs to `self.thirdTextField`

Or any random combination thereof. The `UILabel`'s are all correct - however it seems the actual `UItextField`s have gotten mixed up. the first `UICollectionViewCell`'s `UitextField` will actually have data from another cell's textField.

At first I figured it was a reuse issue - however, since my cells never scroll off screen and the data is pretty static, (There were always X amount of cells, no less or more ) - so it can't be a reuse issue.

I reworked the code so that I have no `UitextField` `Properties` in my `UIViewController` where this code sits - and rely on `indexPath` to get the textField. Like this in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
switch (indexPath.item){
                case 0:
                    label = @"Label One";
                    textFieldCell.textField.text = self.viewModel.labeloneData;
                    break;
```

and:

```
    -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCellContaininView:textField];

    if(indexPath.item == 0){
       //Do something with it
    }
    //And so on for the rest... 
    }
```

This solves the problem however it is not what I want to do. I need the `UItextField` properties in my `UIViewController`

I declared the `UitextField` `Properties` in the implementation like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)  UITextField *firsttextField;
```

I also posted a very similar issue but using `UITableView` instead and it was concluded its related to cell Reuse - however I don't believe it is anymore (Again, setup in that question's code is almost identical to this question - same problem though)

[UITextField in UITableViewCell - reuse issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31532231/uitextfield-in-uitableviewcell-reuse-issue)

**Where the issue is I think**

I don't think it is to do with the the way `UITableView` or `UiCollectionView` is reusing the cells. I think the issue is somewhere in the `viewController's` code and the instances of my `UItextField` properties.. I may be off base here though.

I know I listed a possible workaround - however I would like to get to the bottom of this issue and find how why it's happening.

Comment: did you try giving tags to textfields?

Comment: I thought about this - would I set the tags inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: yes....try giving tags on cellforrowatindex

Comment: It is exactly a reuse problem, and your solution where you find the index path in didEndEditing works.  Why aren't you satisfied with it?

Comment: Not sure how this will solve the issue though. Can you elaborate some some more, please?

Comment: @danh because I need to use properties on the viewModel as it works with ReactiveCocoa.

Comment: I don't think you do.  See here: https://gist.github.com/bunnyhero/9988574

Comment: @danh Actually that's interesting and something I had not considered. Will try it out and report back. Thank you.

Comment: @danh Could you move your comments into an answer. Ultimately it lead to a solution where I can use ReactiveCocoa and no properties. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping pointers to subviews of UITableView/UICollectionView cells is fraught because the cells are reused when scrolling -- and potentially scrambled on reload.  Upon reuse, the subview which you thought was at one index path is now at another.

The most common solution for this is outlets in a custom cell.  Others keep a tag up-to-date every time a cell is configured.  Others favor a quick search up the view hierarchy (say, upon a button tap) to work out which index path a subview corresponds to.

But since ReactiveCocoa is all about model-view connection it wants a pair of pointers for the duo.  Fortunately it also provides and end condition that corresponds to cell reuse.  [This gist demonstrates](https://gist.github.com/bunnyhero/9988574) how to build reactive connection for table view cell's subview.  Copied here ...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    UITableViewCell *cell =
        [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:REUSABLE_CELL_ID];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:VIEW_TAG];
    Model *someModel = [self getModelFromIndexPath:indexPath];
    //  `takeUntil:` makes the RACObserve() signal complete (and thus breaks the subscription)
    //  when the cell is recycled.
    RAC(label, text) = [RACObserve(someModel, someKey)
        takeUntil:cell.rac_prepareForReuseSignal];
    return cell;
}
```